# Jetpack Compose - MotionLayout - Json syntax

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-motionlayout

How is it possible in Jetpack Compose `MotionLayout` to do this kind of thing :

```xml
motion:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
motion:layout_contrainedVertical_bias=1.0
```

Is there a list of Json parameters somewhere ?

Answer (score 2):

`motion:layout_constrainedHeight="true"` - is the equivalent of `width: 'perferWrap'`
`motion:layout_contrainedVertical_bias` - bias is not implemented yet. (should be next release)

[The JSON syntax is being written](https://github.com/androidx/constraintlayout/wiki/ConstraintSet-JSON5-syntax)

file issues in the git hub if you want clarification of the documentation.